# What is wrong with my while else code?

Tags: python, while-loop

I wanted a code that prints hi if the user does not type in 1,2,3, else it asks the user to type in an answer again. However, I don't understand what is wrong with my code. However, whatever I type in, the loop will keep asking me to input the number again.

```
choice=input('Your choice:')
while(choice != 1 or choice !=2 or choice != 3):
    choice=input('Please input only 1, 2 or 3:')
    print(choice)
else:
    print('hi')
```

Thank you!

Comment: choice is a string, not an integer

Comment: Also your logic is wrong, what if it *was* `1`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - It looks like the description is wrong, it states it wants to print hi if the user *doesn't* type in one of those numbers

Comment: @Ev.Kounis what if `choice = 1`, which branch gets executed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh.. The same holds for all of them actually (`1`, `2`, `3`). `while choice not in (1, 2, 3):` would be the way to go.

Comment: Hmm, since this question is not tagged python3, are you sure it is a duplicate ? and not just what @jonrsharpe says ?

Comment: @Faibbus as the OP didn't provide which interpreter or a [mcve] as to what they mean by *"wrong"*, it seems pointless to reopen without a further [edit] from them, which is what the banner suggests they do anyway.